# State not updating when blur effect called on navigation of screen

Tags: react-navigation

When i go to the other screen and come back the paused state is not updating its value

> import * as React from 'react';
> import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
> import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
> import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
>
> function SettingsScreen({ navigation }) {
> return (
> <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
> Settings Screen
> <Button
> title="Go to Profile"
> onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')}
> />
>
> );
> }
>
> function ProfileScreen({ navigation }) {
> const [paused, setPaused] = React.useState(false);
>
> React.useEffect(() => {
> const blurListener = navigation.addListener('blur', () => setPaused(true));
> const focusListener = navigation.addListener('focus', () => setPaused(false));
>
> Clean up the listeners when component unmounts
> return () => {
> blurListener
> focusListener
> };
> [navigation]);
>
> React.useEffect(() => {
> console.log("Paused state changed:", paused);
> [paused]);
> return (
> <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
> Profile Screen
> <Button
> title="Go to Settings"
> onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')}
> />
>
> );
> }
>
> const SettingsStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
>
> export default function App() {
> return (
>
> <SettingsStack.Navigator>
> <SettingsStack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
> <SettingsStack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
> </SettingsStack.Navigator>
>
> );
> }

Comment: Please provide code with proper indentation and inside code blocks. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks